# Traveling Wave Solution for Burgers' Equation

Tags: partial-differential-equations, fluid-dynamics

Let be
$$ \partial_t q + \partial_x (q^2 /2) = \epsilon \partial_{xx}q$$

$$ \begin{equation}
   q_0(x) = q(x, 0) =
   \begin{cases}
     q_l & x<0 \\
     q_r &  x \ge 0 
   \end{cases}
\end{equation}  $$

the viscous Burgers' equation.

By inserting it's easy to verify that the "traviling wave" solution $q_{\epsilon} (x,t) :=w((x-st)/ \epsilon) = w(\xi)$ solves the problem for $q_l > q_r$ (!) with abbreviations

$\xi := (x-st)/ \epsilon$,

$s := (q^2_l /2 - q^2_r /2)/(q_l -q_r)$ and

$w(\xi) := q_r + 1/2(q_l - q_r)(1-tanh((q_l + q_r)\xi/4))$

My question is why do there not exist "traveling wave" solutions for $q_l < q_r$ ?

Comment: Why do you think it doesn't exist? Isn't it a similar solution, travelling in the other direction?

Comment: When $q_r > q_l$ you get a rarefaction wave instead of a traveling wave solution. You should be able to verify that the given solution is not valid when $q_r>q_l$. [By the way, $q_l>q_r$ is the Entropy Condition for solutions of Burger's equation.]

Comment: @toliveira: I suppose that for $q_l < q_r$ there occurs maybe a convergence problem for $\epsilon \to 0$ so here we get a rarefaction wave and not a shock... but I don't see why...